# Find the first terms of the Laurent series for: $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2-1}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laurent-series

$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^2-1}$ for $|z|>1$

I factored out the denominator and rewrote it to a geometric series and got the following expression:

$$e^{1/z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z^2)^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^nn!}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z^2)^{n+1}}$$

Now to evaluate the first terms I figured I'd use the Cauchy product which give me:

$$\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{z^4}$$

But this isn't correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The coefficient of $z^{-4}$ is $3/2$.

Comment: Yes I know - that's what the answer is. But I don't know why.

Comment: Your series expansion for $\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ is wrong! It should be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{2(n+1)}}$. Notice the condition $|z|>1$. By taking that into consideration, the coefficient of $z^{-4}$ is $-1/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left(1+\frac1z+\frac1{2z^2}+\cdots\right)\left(\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^4}+\cdots\right)= \cdots+\left(1\frac1{z^4} + \frac1{2z^2}\frac1{z^2}\right)+\cdots$$